# Sorting of Date column which is in string format in Datacolumns

Tags: jquery, reactjs, datatables, primereact

I have a react application in which a Datatable.Columns is used to render a table on the page.

```
<div data-test={"Order-Status"}>
<DataTable data={GetData}>
    {this.displayColumns()}
</DataTable>
</div>



 displayColumns = () => {
    return this.state.selectedColumns.map((col) => {
      if (col.selected) {
        return (
            <DataTable.Column
              field={col.value}
              header={col.text}
              className={col.className}
              sortable={true}
            />
          );       
      }
      return undefined;
    });
  };
  
 const GetData = (this.props.order || []).map((item) => {
        return {
          ...item,
          OrderDate: item.OrderDate(item.orderDate),
       };
      
    });
    
get OrderDate(timeStamp: number | string) {
        if (!timeStamp) return '';
    const date = timeStamp.toString().length >= 13 ? new Date(+timeStamp) : new Date(+timeStamp * 1000);
    const offset = (date.getTimezoneOffset() / -60) .toString().split('.');
    return date.getFullYear() + '.'
        + (Number(date.getMonth()) + 1)
        + '.' + date.getDate()
        + ' - ' + date.toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' })
        + ` (${offset[0]}:${offset[1] ? 60 * Number('0.' + offset[1]) : '00'} UTC)`;
    }
```

The time in the database is in EPOCH time. So we are converting it into human readable time format which is a string and displaying. But the sorting of this date is not working as expected. Since the value of the date is in string , it is sorting the values based on String.
How to sort the dates by converting them to date from string.

Comment: what library are you using for table?

Comment: @Apostolos , It is using prime-react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to set the original field as the `field` property and then format the `body` part of the `Column`

See an example below.

```
  <Column sortable
          field="your_date_field"
          body={rowData => <>{formatDate(rowData.your_date_field}</>}
  />
```